# xautolock locker function stops working after a minute

Tags: xset, xautolock

I have a slightly different way of using xautolock: After I lock the screen (using `i3lock` in my case), I want the display to turn off after some period of time of inactivity. AND I want it to re-turn off if it detects activity, turns on the screen, but the computer isn't unlocked.

Here is the script I have:

```bsh
/bin/bash

function lockfunc {
    if [[ "$1" = -sleep ]]; then
        i3lock -t -i $backgroundimg &&  xautolock -time 1 -locker 'xset s activate' &
        while [[ $(pgrep -x i3lock) ]]; do # loop while computer is locked
            echo $(date) '| i3lock running'
            if [[ $(pgrep -x xautolock) ]]; then echo $(date) '| xautolock running'; fi
            # if $(pgrep -x xautolock); then echo $(date) '| i3lock running'; fi
            sleep 5
        done
        echo $(date) '| exit i3lock while loop'
        xautolock -exit # stop xautolock when unlocked
    else
        i3lock -t -i $backgroundimg
    fi
    return 0}

lockfunc -sleep
```

While the behavior mostly works, the huge issue right now is that **after (exactly) one minute of the screen being off, it turns back on without any interaction.**

Behavior timeline:

```
00:00 -> start the lockfunc
01:00 -> screen turns off
02:00 -> screen turns on
07:00 -> screen doesn't turn back off, stop test
```

The debug `echo` statements in the script above didn't really show anything changing during that time: both i3lock and xautolock were still running the whole time.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `xset s activate` --> `xset dpms force off` did the trick.

Weird thing that would be nice to explain is that when I used `xset s activate` outside of `xautolock`, it did not demonstrate this behavior. Any explanation as to why would be appreciated.